# Maxima of a sequence of real positive numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{R_+}$ a sequence of real positive numbers such that 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a $$ 
and $0<a<\infty$

I would like to know if is true that
$\exists m \in \mathbb{N} : a_n \leq a_m \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: let $a_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$, but the set $\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ has no maximum.